# I'm getting 'Bad Login' when attempting to join multiplayer servers in Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I can login to minecraft fine through the launcher and play singleplayer just fine. But when I go into multiplayer it won't let me join any server. It just keeps saying "Bad Login".

I do have a paid account and this has never happened to me before. What could cause this? 
I have no mods installed and the server is up to date

Comment: When did this start happening? After you did something?

Comment: Do you have any mods installed? Have you got the [latest launcher](https://minecraft.net/download)? Are you up to date? Is the server up to date?

Comment: This has started happening to me as well on Vanilla Minecraft with the latest launcher, even on my own server being run on my machine. Would be interested to find the answer.

Comment: @Robotnik I had the same issue with a self-run server, two days ago everything worked perfectly, yesterday I could not enter multiplayer because "Bad login". Restarting the game and server did not fix anything, rebooting the pc didn't help. I gave an answer with the thing that did work.

Answer (score 3):

You can fix it by re-entering your password before you login and start up the game.

I had the same issue with a custom launcher, after re-entering the password it fixed itself.

Answer (score 0):

Keep on log into the server over and over until you can join it.